# What causes 'Invalid form POST data' when removing an attached file from a node?

Tags: 7, nodes, files

I have an attached PDF file on a file field. When I click the 'Remove' button, the AJAX throbber appears and then the file remains unremoved. Adding an file to a new node still works.

I checked the error logs; it states "Invalid form POST data."

What is causing this problem?

Comment: Do you see any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Negative. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is look through the Drupal / Apache logs for some indication of a PHP error. Without any hints of abnormality, there's no way to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: I just had a look at the Drupal logs and I'm seeing an AJAX error with the message: "Invalid form POST data"

Comment: That errors is likely too broad to answer succinctly here, but that should give you clue what's going on. For some reason, the data being POST'd is not being accepted as valid. If I had to guess, it might be another contrib module causing issues, but that's just speculation.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the input. I have found an article that talks about AJAX requests terminating abnormally in Drupal. Their solution had to do with their MySQL configuration and the 'max_allowed_pack' being set too low. I'm going to speak with a colleague and see if this is the cause of our issues.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm, increasing 'max_allowed_packet' in our MySQL config solved this problem. MySQL's default of 1 megabyte was too small. Increasing it to 16M, then restarting MySQL has resolved this issue.

Info on our solution was found here:
https://www.shift8web.ca/blog/2014/11/drupal-problem-an-ajax-http-request-terminated-abnormally/